# How to calculate the averages of a variable in one binary file based on classes in another binary file?

Tags: r, binary, raster

I have two binary files(raster) with the same dimensions: the first represents correlation between 2 data and the second represents land cover map with 10 classes.I want take the average of my correlations based on the land cover classes. So finally we will got a map as the same as land cover map but with averages of correlations instead of the classes numbers.

Here are the two files:

```
  1- to read the first file correlation map:

   conne <- file("C:\\corr.bin","rb")
  corr<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
  y<-t(matrix((data=corr), ncol=720, nrow=1440))
    r = raster(y)
```

2- to read the second file land cover map:

```
  conne <- file("C:\\land cover.bin","rb")
  over<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=1,  n=1440*720, signed=F)
  y1<-t(matrix((data=over), ncol=720, nrow=1440))
  r1 = raster(y1)
```

3-to write the results:

```
     to.write = file(paste("/orcomplete.bin",sep=""),"wb")
     writeBin(as.double(results), to.write, size = 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this just be something like:

```
 tapply(y, y1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you want the class mean associated with the same arrangement as the input matrices then do this:

```
outmat <- matrix( ave( y, y1, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE), nrow(y), ncol(y) )
```

Comment: I'm surprised you got such a large file. (And also surprised you thought it would be even larger.) You said that `y1` only had 10 classes. I would have predicted you would only get a vector of length 10. What does head(result) look like?

Comment: If you want the class mean to be replicated in the same arrangement as the data then I would do it differently. Editing above.

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

If the landcover raster has geo-referencing characteristics you would like to keep (e.g., projection information), you can use the zonal tool from the raster toolbox:

```
corr_raster <- raster('correlation raster filename')
land_raster <- raster('landcover raster filename')
zv <- zonal(corr_raster , land_raster, fun=mean)
```

Then all you have to do is assign the mean values from the resulting table to the landcover pixels. The raster package has plenty of substitution methods to do that (e.g. reclassify function).